# MyBatis query not returning values when using a join

Tags: postgresql, mybatis

This is probably something stupid, but I've not been able to find it. I'm using MyBatis 3.2.2, PostgreSQL 9.2.2, and XML mappings, although I had the same experience with annotations. I've set up a simple select that returns a list of objects. This configuration works as expected:

```
<select id="getCasesBySite" parameterType="string" resultType="Case">
  select c.* from cases c
</select>
```

and returns a list of Case objects. This however returns nothing:

```
<select id="getCasesBySite" parameterType="string" resultType="Case">
  select c.* from cases c join siteinfo s on c.siteid = s.id where s.key=#{site}
</select>
```

My mapper interface has this:

```
List<Case> getCasesBySite(@Param("site") String site);
```

Debug logging for the version that uses a join is:

```
... ==>  Preparing: select c.* from cases c join siteinfo s on c.siteid = s.id where s.key=?
... ==> Parameters: sw(String)
```

If I copy the above SQL and paste it into my psql command line (replacing ? with 'sw'), I receive a list of results, so it looks like the join query itself is OK.

Is there something else I should be doing? This is driving me nuts. I remember there being an issue with case sensitivity when working with PostgreSQL, but if that's the problem I'm not sure how to address it.

I can include more information. I just wasn't sure what was relevent.

Comment: I can simplify the queries down to this one works: `select c.* from cases c where c.siteid = 1` and this one does not: `select c.* from cases c join siteinfo s on c.siteid = s.id where s.id = 1`, although running the second directly in psql gives the same results as the first one.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After much debugging, the problem appears to be related to transactions and our testing framework. We're using Unitils to handle refreshing test data, and we found that after setting this property:

```
DatabaseModule.Transactional.value.default=disabled
```

in the `unitils.properties` file, the tests all ran as expected.